# BerkeleyDB - implications of incorrect sorting order?

Tags: berkeley-db

According to this [FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/berkeleydb/db-faq-095848.html), page fill factor can be adversely affected by not specifying a sorting function for binary data on little-endian systems.  I understand that it will also result in cursors not returning data in the "correct" sorted order.

Other than excessive page usage, would this cause any other performance issues?  For example, does a poor page fill factor adversely affect the speed of key lookups?

Furthermore, if I have data already stored in a BTREE *without* a sorting function, will anything break if I subsequently start using a sorting function to add new records?  i.e. would a mismatch between the originally used sort order and a new sort function break key lookups?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, incorrect endian-ness can reduce your fill factor and as a result your database will be bigger and slower to acess. Today I was inserting about 30 million records with a sequential integer key and noticed quite poor btree fill factor (60%). Then changed the endianness of the key (used htonl() function) and the fill factor jumped to 99%. At the same time database size was reduced from 1.3 GB to 700 MB.
Endianness is important when your key is sequential or shows some locality (common prefix for related data). For some keys changing the endianness could worsen the performance (I experienced this with mobile phone numbers).
BTW you don't have to provide a sorting function - you can just convert the keys to correct endianness when inserting and searching by key.